# How to check what all URLs are available on a particular server?

Tags: http, url, unix

On a machine, there is a HTTP server running at a particular port. I know some of the pages that are accessible:

```
http://myothermachine.tx:6566/info
http://myothermachine.tx:6566/status
```

etc.

The pages that are not accessible will result in 404's.

Is there a way I can find out what all URIs do not result in 404's?

Comment: Ask the site owner for a sitemap?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, **there is no standard way to do this**. There exists no 'universal query' which asks for the machine to respond with a list of all accessible URLs.

However, a couple of things you could try:

- Check the machine's documentroot. See what files exist.
- Check the webserver configuration. See what mappings exist.
- Check what applications are deployed on the machine.
- Check if there is a robots.txt
- Check for links to the machine on other sites
- Use a search engine, of the machine is indexed
- Brute-force the machine, trying every possible combination. Not very friendly...